# How can I controll the speed of motor using gears?

Tags: motor, gears

Can anyone tell me how to use gear wheels to modify the speed of the motor in the Power Functions set 8293?

I know I could use the remote control unit, but I need to have a fixed slow speed on a static unit which will power a non-LEGO moving toy. I need a slow turning axle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sariel's tutorial](http://sariel.pl/2009/09/gears-tutorial/) is one of the better ones, and his whole web site is worth while. The Eurobricks Technic forum also has a [list of tutorials](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=40498) thread that you might find helpful.

Sariel starts very simple and ends up with a discussion of what makes different variants on some of the Lego gears effective...

[image: sample image from Sariel]